Movie about drowned lesbian
Sorry for mistakes, English is not my first language. 

In the 80s or 90s
It is about two women in their 30's. One of them is single and bohemian. The other is married and lives with her husband and mother-in-law. I think she has a child.
They meet on seaside closed because of flux and reflux. The married woman goes to the city to meet the single one.
At the end of movie, the woman who single called to woman who married. The married woman tried to pass this road but drowned in the waves.
I don't know language. I watched dubbed

New details
The grandson of the dead homosexual and is beginning to be loved in the family. They look like bad boys because they do it. Especially the father is bad with his father, and his father knows why his mother died. But no one expresses it shamefully for the sake of society, so nobody knows, including the child. He's investigating and finding out how his grandmother died. On every occasion, the film goes back and talks about that part of the story of two women with long sections. Then it goes back to the original time and goes back to the past a few frames and again from the child's quest. The child and grandmother went to the past to find out the cause of death and showed the film and the event completely. The person who called her was the person who opened her phone, her mother-in-law knew what happened, and she began to threaten her. She did not say that the phone was arriving that day anyway, she learned in some way and ran to the car to go to town. After drowning, her husband found her in the morning and ran to the car saying the name of the woman.

Boomerang (2015)

Antoine Rey looks for a special gift for his sister Melanie on her
  40th birthday. He decides to surprise her with a trip to the French
  Island of Noirmoutier, where they spent many summers as children until
  their mother's death. On the drive back to Paris, Melanie is seriously
  injured in a car accident...




In the flashback: 
There is a debate between young women and mother-in-law. Because  young woman is having an affair with another woman.
The woman's car "Gois Passage"  tide was caught in. And woman drowns.

Is there anything about this movie claiming that the woman who drowned was a lesbian? There is really not a lot of plot information on this movie.  It might help if you explained how this movie fits with what OP is looking for.  Thanks :)

Sorry, my English is not enough. But I checked it by watching the movie.

@VinsmokeSanji But 2015 is not "In the 80s or 90s" :o

@  Lord of dark I saw the question on another site. Flashback scenes in the 1980's.   He meant that.

@ Lord of dark İ confused with flashbacks :)
